# Pythonista way of extracting elements from an array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a few Python lines of code doing the following:

I have two arrays a and b, b contains (non strictly) increasing integers.

I want to extract from a the values for which the values of b is a multiple of 20 but I don't want duplicates, in the sense that if b has values : ...,40,40,41,... I only want the first value in a corresponding the 40 not the second one.

That's why `a[b%20==0]` does not work.

I've been using:

```
factors = [20*i for i in xrange(1,int(b[-1]/20 +1))]
sample = numpy.array([a[numpy.nonzero(b==factor)[0][0]] for factor in factors])
```

but it is both slow and fairly inelegant.

Is there a Pythonista 'cute' way of doing it?

Comment: What do you mean "extract from a the values for which the values in b" - for each value of `a`, you want to check the corresponding value (at the same position) in `b` and then if that value from `b` is a multiple of 20, you want to extract that out - is that it?

Comment: I'd say there's no "Pythonic" way to do that, because you're playing with NumPy, with its own set of rules if you want to do things efficiently. I think there's a way to do it using `numpy.unique`. Let's see...

Comment: I want to extract a subset of a, can be a list or a numpy array. a and b have same length I should have specified that. This subset corresponds to the values of a for which the value in b (at the same index value) corresponds to a multiple of 20 appearing for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a[(b % 20 == 0) & np.r_[True, np.diff(b) > 0]]
```

The `b % 20 == 0` part gives a binary mask that selects all the elements of b that are a factor of 20. The `np.r_[True, np.diff(b) > 0]` part creates a binary mask that selects only the elements that differ from the previous element (we explicitly add a True at the beginning, as the first element does not have a previous element). Add the masks together and voila!

Comment: You could just use `np.unique` for the second part. I think that makes it the same as Ricardo's method.

Comment: that depends on the desired behavior. if the sequence is [20, 20, 40, 20] which indices should be returned? `diff` returns [0, 2, 3], `unique` returns [0, 2]

Comment: Mmh... Didn't think of using `np.diff` to exploit the fact that `b` is sorted (totally overlooked that fact). Mine is more generic.

Comment: @Rodin I'd say `[0, 2]`, but that's out of the scope of the problem, because `b` is monotonic increasing

Comment: Thank you very elegant, I had thought about `numpy.diff` but I was embarrassed by losing one element in length. Thank you, just added `numpy.r_` to my toolbox ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we create a boolean array wich marks the unique values on `b`:

```
c = np.zeros(b.shape, dtype=np.bool)
c[np.unique(b, return_index = True)[1]] = True
```

Now you can do:

```
a[np.logical_and(b % 20 == 0, c)]
```

Comment: Fixed for `np.unique`. I was not returning the indices of the unique elements, as I intended

Comment: Thank you, this made me discover the `return_index` feature of `numpy.unique`, very useful here ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your b is sorted, using `diff` should be a bit faster than using `unique`:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.random.random_integers(0, 1000, 1000)
b = numpy.random.random_integers(0, 1000, 1000)
b.sort()

subset = a[(numpy.diff(b) != 0) * (b[:-1]%20 == 0)]
```